# Bytes decoding in D

Tags: utf-8, d, cp866

I've got some wrongly decoded text fragment. It was decoded like *cp866*, but in fact it should be *utf-8* (`"нажал кабан на баклажан"` --> `"╨╜╨░╨╢╨░╨╗ ╨║╨░╨▒╨░╨╜ ╨╜╨░ ╨▒╨░╨║╨╗╨░╨╢╨░╨╜"`). I'd like to fix it, and I've already written the code in **Python** which solves the task:

```
broken = "╨╜╨░╨╢╨░╨╗ ╨║╨░╨▒╨░╨╜ ╨╜╨░ ╨▒╨░╨║╨╗╨░╨╢╨░╨╜"
fixed = bytes(broken, 'cp866').decode('utf-8')
print(fixed) # it will print 'нажал кабан на баклажан'
```

However, at first I was trying to solve this issue in **D**, but failed to find an answer. So, how can this task be solved in **D**?

Comment: [std.encoding](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_encoding.html) will help, but it doesn't look like cp866 is supported

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment, D does not have extensive native facilities for converting text between encodings.

Here are some options:

- As ratchet freak mentioned, D does have [std.encoding](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_encoding.html), but it does not cover many encodings at the moment.
- On Windows, you could use `std.windows.charset.fromMBSz` and `toMBSz`, which wrap `MultiByteToWideChar` and `WideCharToMultiByte`.
- You could simply embed the encodings that interest you in your program ([example](https://github.com/CyberShadow/ae/blob/master/utils/iconv.d)).
- On POSIX, you could invoke the `iconv` program ([example](https://github.com/CyberShadow/ae/blob/master/sys/cmd.d#L523-L526)), or use the `libiconv` library ([D1 binding](http://www.algonet.se/~afb/d/libiconv.d)).

Comment: The advice about **std.windows.charset** was very useful. The sollution for Windows is something like `fixed = fromMBSz(cast(immutable)toMBSz(broken,866),65001)`